# Jquery Callback Was Not Called

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I've Googled every instance of this error I can find, and none of the solutions work for me. In essence, I am doing what others have suggested. Despite that, I am receiving an error that my callback function is not being called. I am using Ajax/Jquery/JASONP to do a cross domain form submission using GET. Here is my code on the form side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#ajaxform1").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var surl = "http://blahblah/test_create_user.php?callback=?";

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: surl,
            crossDomain: true,
                data:  $('#ajaxform1').serialize(),
                dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(msg) {

            $.each(msg, function (index, value) {
             if(value==1)
              {
            alert("New User Added");
                  }   else {
              alert("User Already Exists")
                   }                     }
             });

                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var myerror = xhr+" "+status+" "+error;
            alert("Failure Connecting to Kayako. Please Try    Again("+myerror+")"); }

            });
```

Here is the applicable snippet of my PHP Code:

```
if($USER_CHK->first()->id){
  $data = array('msg' => '0'); // user exists
  else {
            $data = array('msg' => '1'); // User added
       }
    //echo customerAdded(FALSE);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization,X-   Requested-      With');
    header("Content-type: application/json");  
    $data = array('msg' => '0');
    print $_REQUEST['callback']. '('.json_encode($data).')'; 
    exit;

      });           
            });
```

My debugging shows that all form variables are getting posted.
The PHP code returns: jQuery11020900643879813015_1397599599587({"msg":"1"})
Yet the error indicating the callback was not called is thrown.

Comment: i am not sure, but the response `content-type` should be `application/x-javascript`

Comment: Thanks Shakib. I changed it, but still no prize.

Answer (score 0):

How does the request looks like on the server side?

I have a working example which is very similar to what you have.  The only difference is that the content type I am replying with is:

```
'text/javascript'
```

Also, my JSONP message includes a semicolon at the end (which I think is not really a cause for failure).

```
returnJSONP = $_REQUEST['callback']. '('.json_encode($data).');';
```

If you were able to resolve, could you please post the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to get this working and, instead, posted to a local php script which then used CURL to post to the remote server. I echo the CURL results back to the jQuery function and all works well.